# Cache validation - Browsers validate cookies in cache incorrectly?

Tags: php, validation, caching, browser, cookies

I have the following situation:

- User makes request to PAGE A that displays a form (server stores cache of this page)
- User submits the form to CONTROLLER that is used for form submit
- CONTROLLER finds an error in user submitted data, sets a cookie ERRORS detailing such, and redirects the user back to PAGE A
- PAGE A shows the original content plus the ERRORS (server stores cache of this page)
- PAGE A deletes ERRORS cookie

This works, but only if I don't use cache on my system for PAGE A.

Problem is that, after deleting the cookie, browser makes a request to my server without the cookie and gets a 304 Not Modified error and, as a result, the browser still shows the page with the error, instead of without (from the original request). Server stores cache properly (for page that has an error as well as an error-free page).

Basically the server has two cached pages now: PAGE A and PAGE A WITH ERRORS.

Browser, whose last known page was PAGE A WITH ERRORS asks for server a page with conditions of PAGE A, instead of PAGE A WITH ERRORS, since cookie does not exist anymore. But it thinks that the 304 response is about the PAGE A WITH ERRORS, instead of PAGE A. I even checked the data sent by the browser, it knows that it got PAGE A WITH ERRORS with the ERRORS cookie, yet accepts 304 not modified when making requests without that cookie. It does not validate its own cache against the conditions it was created under.

Doesn't browser validate its cache with the cookies it has set?

And is there a workaround for it without setting some GET variables for each request? Another alternative is to tell servers to never cache pages that have such an ERRORS state set, but that would be a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the solution was to include this as a response header:

```
Vary: Cookie
```

This will take cookies into account in caching engines.

EDIT:

There is a problem though: Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox work as expected, but Safari and Opera both ignore 'Vary' header when storing and validating cache.

Answer (score 1):

client-side sessions (a.k.a cookies) are probably not sufficient for this scenario...
would suggest server-side sessions instead. Even if Vary headers might work - with $_SESSION you'll be on the save side.

Comment: This is incorrect, server side sessions still require a cookie to work, so it has the exact same amount of problems.

Comment: Of course - it's just more handy to have the variables available on the server-side, not just within a cookie on the client-side. For example: Many WordPress blogs get hacked because people login from inet cafés (or other public computers) - and get their client-side session-storage hi-jacked, so this also a matter of security. Your answer is certainly correct according to the question - I just wanted to question the scenario.

Comment: yeah, use the cookies only for identification and pass error messages between pages on the server side instead (using $_SESSION).

Comment: Best practice is to analyze the concrete requirements and not store any more than required on the client-side. That can't be generalized because it depends on the application - and how portable it shall be. With my WP example it's implemented like this in order to run on any crap hosting, even without the session module loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Cache-control: public is probably not what you want. Public essentially says that you're working with static, globally accessible data. It doesn't change per user. It's caching globally because you're claiming that the data is global.

As soon as you start changing per user, caches are having their assumptions violated. 'private' is more akin to what you want.

That will mean that you get less of the good middle-man caching, however. You might be able to hit some middle ground with re-validation, or with appropriate use of Vary headers.

Comment: That does not work though, the only difference between Public and Private is that Private says that only the browser can cache while with Public everyone can. I changed it to Private and the behavior was the same (since it's the browser that doesn't ask for cache when making a request). I changed it to private in the original question just to be sure.